# does mass of elctron should also be calculated in inductance

Tags: electric-current

according to ohms law V=RI if R is zero then current should instantly be infinity if in a vacuum tube electron is made run under some potential difference is applied but it tends towards infinity slowly so should we take electron mass under inductance

Comment: Your question seems to confuse inductance and impedance; also, when an electron moves in vacuum, you should solve its equation of motion (which includes the mass) but you don't typically consider the inductance (or impedance) of the vacuum part of a "circuit", as the electron is not constrained by the inductor. Perhaps you can clarify your question so it can be answered more succinctly.

Comment: *"according to ohms law V=RI if R is zero then current should instantly be infinity"* - this is false.  Ohm's law implies there is 0V across a resistance of 0 ohms for *any* finite current through.

Comment: *"in a vacuum tube"* - vacuum tubes are not resistors, are not ohmic, do not obey Ohm's law.  Ohm's law describes ideal resistors, not vacuum tubes.  See [Child–Langmuir equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_charge#Child's_law)